# Duplication in XAML styles

Tags: xaml, xaml-resources

I have xaml styles that have different target types but are otherwise identical. Is there a way I could cut out the duplication and define the style only once?

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">            
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource ElementHeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{StaticResource ElementMinWidth}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource ElementMargin}"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource ElementHeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{StaticResource ElementMinWidth}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource ElementMargin}"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource ElementHeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{StaticResource ElementMinWidth}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource ElementMargin}"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use style inheritance with the help of [Style.BasedOn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx).

First define the base style:

```
   <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="80"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="80"/>
    </Style>
```

Then "inherit" styles from that for the controls you want:

```
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"/>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"/>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I didn't think of targeting `FrameworkElement`.